# filter AngularJS return multiples element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using filter of angularjs and i'm trying to get element that has the same date, by doing this :

```
  $scope.getFilebyDate= function(date){           

            return $filter('filter')($scope.files, moment(date).format("YYYYMMDDHHmmss"));

        }
```

my files array is composed like this

```
[["20011110000000","#DT#20011110000000#ED#20021110000000Filename1"],
["20011110000000","#DT#20011110000000#ED#20021110000000#Filename2"],
["20021110000000","#DT#20021110000000#Filename3"] ]
```

My problem is that my function is not working properly i want to filter only using the first column and what i have done seem to look for dates even in the second column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to only filter on the first "column" of your array you probably want to pass in an expression function as the second parameter of your `$filter` function call, here you can make a specific comparison of your formatted `date` with the first item/column in the array:

```
$filter('filter')($scope.files, function(value, index, array) {
  return value[0] === moment(date).format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss');
});
```

see this plnkr for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/kvfMnNoIMi7q1D4ChDIJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be lacking an argument to the filter function. Here's the syntax taken from the [AngularJS filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter): `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`